# OBJ file not loading in GIScene.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, html, three-js

I am trying to load a OBJ file in GIScene.js. Unfortunately, the OBJ file is not getting visualized inside scene of GIScene.js, even though the scene of GIScene.js is getting visualized. There are no errors and I don't think that there is any issue in the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>GIScene.js Scene</title>
<script src = "three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script> 
<script src="GIScene_1.0.1/GIScene_min_1.0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>GIScene.js - Scene</h1>
    <div id="scene"></div>
    <script>
        var scene = new GIScene.Scene('scene');
        
        var layer_options = {
            url : "Tree1.obj",
            format : GIScene.Format.OBJ
        };
        
        var layer = new GIScene.Layer.Fixed("Layername", layer_options);
        
        scene.addLayer(layer);
        
        var nav_ctrl = new GIScene.Control.PanOrbitZoomCenter(scene.camera);
        
        scene.addControl(nav_ctrl);
        
        nav_ctrl.activate();
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The examples (https://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/examples/index.html) are using either CTM or JSON files for loading inside the scene of GIScene.js, none of the examples are showing how to visualize OBJ files. How can I solve this issue ?